# How to set the initial value of a state variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[This page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) says "The only argument to the useState() Hook is the initial state."

I interpret that to mean that useState takes one argument and that argument is the initial state.  That appears to be incorrect so my question is how do I set the initial value of a state variable?  In the following line of code `message` is always an empty string even though I am setting it to a valid string value.

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState(props.message);
```

My dialog is passed a string by the host component (`props.message`).  I want to assign that string to a state variable (`message`) then assign `message` the empty string when the user wants to close the dialog.

Dialog.tsx

```
function Dialog(props: any) {
    var dummy = props.message;                                 // "foo"
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(props.message);     // set initial state     
    dummy = message;                                           // "" - expected "foo"

    const handleClose = () => setMessage('');

    return (
        <>
            <Modal show={message.length > 1} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Information</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>{message}</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Ok
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: What is `dummy` for? Are you saying that you wanted to set props.message to be the value `message` from your useState? Also, check the value of `props.message` before useState

Comment: I am using `dummy` to illustrate that `props.message` actually has a value and that `message` is not being set to that value.

Comment: `useState(value)` sets the state only once at the first render. You could e.g. `console.log(props.message)`. I guess it will be logged more than once, and the first time it is an empty string.